# Using context connection=true for SqlConnection

Tags: c#, dapper

I have this simplified class:

```
public abstract class BaseDaService
{
    private readonly string _connectionString;

    protected BaseDaService(string connectionString)
    {
        _connectionString = connectionString;
        }

        protected IDbConnection OpenConnection()
    {
        IDbConnection connection = new SqlConnection(_connectionString);
        connection.Open();
        return connection;
        }
}
```

Here the connection string comes from a config file. I would like to use credentials from my config files whilst doing:

[new SqlConnection("context connection=true")](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms131053.aspx)

Can I adapt the connection string in the config file or manipulate the 'connection' instance of IDbConnection to achieve this?

Comment: Would this work? `SqlConnectionStringBuilder sqlb = new SqlConnectionStringBuilder(_connectionString); sqlb.ContextConnection = true;`

Comment: Thanks, was looking for this. Will give it a go.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest to use the [SqlConnectionStringBuilder](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlconnectionstringbuilder(v=vs.110).aspx) class

```
 // With a default parameter set to false you can still use
 // the same code as before and change only the spots where
 // the context is required
 protected IDbConnection OpenConnection(bool useContext = false)
 {

    string newConString = _connectionString;
    if(useContext)
    {
        SqlConnectionStringBuilder scs = new SqlConnectionStringBuilder(_connectionString);
        scs.ContextConnection = true;
        newConString = scs.ToString();
    }
    IDbConnection connection = new SqlConnection(newConString);
    connection.Open();
    return connection
}
```

Of course changing the app.config is just a matter of preference.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `SqlConnectionStringBuilder` in order to change the connection string which you have already retrieved from the config file. That means you could as well keep your original connection string readonly.

```
SqlConnectionStringBuilder sqlb = new SlConnectionStringBuilder(_connectionString); 
sqlb.ContextConnection = true;
string modifiedConnString = sqlb.ToString();
```